# How can I import from a library when there is no type defined for that single value

Tags: typescript, react-spring

I am working on a project that uses a component library that uses react-spring. I have no control over the component library and thus I have no control the fact that it uses react-spring v8

I found a [comment](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-spring/pull/866#pullrequestreview-319189789) on a PR that tells me how to fix animations when running in a test environment. It requires me to import the `Globals` object. When I attempt to do so via `import { Globals }` I get the error message `Module '"react-spring"' has no exported member 'Globals'.ts(2305)` as my project is using Typescript (where as the instructions are for JS)

When I take a look at the code in my node_modules directory for react-spring I can see that the `Globals` object is definitely exported both in the main and module code.

web.js (main):

```
export { apply, config, update, extendedAnimated as animated, extendedAnimated as a, interpolate$1 as interpolate, Globals, useSpring, useTrail, useTransition, useChain, useSprings };
```

web.cjs.js (module):

```
exports.Globals = Globals;
```

However when I look at the [types provide by react-spring](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-spring/blob/8.0.27/types/web.d.ts), there is nothing for `Globals` and I worry that this is what is causing me to be unable to import the Globals so that I can provide a mock requestAnimationFrame during testing as instructed.

I am pretty new to Typescript so it's possible I am misunderstanding something and I have tried to *Google* the solution but I can pretty much only find out how to deal with a library that has no types at all but not anything on how to fix a "hole" inside library provided types.

Here is a CodeSandbox that exhibits the same error (must be editing the sandbox. Doesn't show in preview mode.

[image: Edit zen-morning-5843r]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a Typescript error in `react-spring@8` because yes, `Globals` is exported. If you're interested in making a PR against the v8 branch we can release this fix.

If you want an immediate fix, you can add this:

```
declare module "react-spring" {
  interface Globals {
    injectFrame: () => void;
  }

  export const Globals: Globals;
}
```

normally to a `*.d.ts` file or just where you need it. Which will give you the function you need, and you can continue to add more where you need it. Else you could use `// @ts-expect-error` to mute the error.

This is a sandbox demonstrating the resolution – https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-frog-5enu2?file=/src/App.tsx